# Edit AWS Cognito Identity Pool using serverless.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I am configuring an AWS Cognito Identity Pool using the severless framework, and I am editing a file in the yml configuration to add an unauthenticated role for users to upload an image to an s3 bucket.

The code was previously deployed without an unauthenticated role being specified, and the deployment went fine and was stable. After I went looking for a way to control the permissions regarding accessing the S3 bucket, I discovered that the only way to give write, but not read, permissions on an S3 bucket is to specify it in a user policy, so I have to add an unathenticated role to the identity pool. However, when I deploy the code, I get an error stating:

```
Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  An error occurred: CognitoIdentityPoolRoles - Resource cannot be updated.
```

I have managed to get around the problem in the dev environment but it required totally deleting the stack and rebuilding it from scratch.

I also do not want to go in and adjust the resources manually in the AWS console since resources should be managed in cloudformation or in the console, but doing it both ways leads to chaos.

So, at the moment, the options I see are to delete the entire stack and rebuild it with the new roles, or find a way to update through cloudformation.

Does anyone have a way to avoid the first option and allow me to update the stack without attaching the role in the console?

Relevant section of serverless.yml is below...

```
Resources:
  # The federated identity for our user pool to auth with
  CognitoIdentityPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::IdentityPool
    Properties:
      # Generate a name based on the stage
      IdentityPoolName: ${self:custom.stage}MyIdentityPool
      # Allow unathenticated users
      AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities: true
      # Link to our User Pool
      CognitoIdentityProviders:
      - ClientId:
          Ref: CognitoUserPoolClient
        ProviderName:
          Fn::GetAtt: [ "CognitoUserPool", "ProviderName" ]

  # IAM roles
  CognitoIdentityPoolRoles:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::IdentityPoolRoleAttachment
    Properties:
      IdentityPoolId:
        Ref: CognitoIdentityPool
      Roles:
        authenticated:
          Fn::GetAtt: [CognitoAuthRole, Arn]
        # Next two lines are the 2 lines of code which break everything
        unauthenticated:
          Fn::GetAtt: [CognitoUnAuthRole, Arn]

  # IAM role for UN-authenticated users
  CognitoUnAuthRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: 'Allow'
          Principal:
            Federated: 'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com'
          Action:
          - 'sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity'
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud':
                Ref: CognitoIdentityPool
            'ForAnyValue:StringLike':
              'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr': unauthenticated
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: 'CognitoUnAuthorizedPolicy'
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Effect: 'Allow'
            Action:
            - 'mobileanalytics:PutEvents'
            - 'cognito-sync:*'
            - 'cognito-identity:*'
            Resource: '*'
          # Allow users to upload attachments to their
          # folder inside our S3 bucket
          - Effect: 'Allow'
            Action:
            - 's3:PutObject'
            Resource:
            - Fn::Join:
              - ''
              -
                - Fn::GetAtt: [MediafilesBucket, Arn]
                - '/submissions/'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

I commented out the sections of serverless.yml related to the identity pool deployed (destroyed), then uncommented that section, redeployed, and restored from backup.

It seems to be a bit of a hack, but it worked.

I also feel like there *should* be a way to edit identity pool roles through cloudformation...